# Does OSX have a nice feature to quickly drag windows via key press?

Tags: macos

### Synopsis

On linux one could hold <kbd>alt</kbd> and then drag any window around from any point within it's focus.  Is there similar functionality on OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend **Better Touch Tool** http://www.boastr.de.
You can customize not only window dragging but also custom gestures, window snapping and more.

Edit:
Dragged window doesn't have to have focus.
[image]

Comment: In reference to your edit - this is great similar to Linux where by 'focus' is based on the object where the mouse sits without the need to focus.  As for the library works a treat :) thanks bru